# How to change response of admin-ajax request?

Tags: plugins, filters, ajax

Request generated by fullcalendar js, which implemented by plugin  [WP FullCalendar](https://github.com/wp-plugins/wp-fullcalendar) (github link for code)

Request url:

`http://sitename/admin-ajax.php?action=WP_FullCalendar&type=event&month=2&year=2019&start=2019-02-25&end=2019-04-08&_=1553274882245`

Plugin contain following code:

`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_WP_FullCalendar', array('WP_FullCalendar','ajax') );`

So i figured out that request should be handled by `WP_FullCalendar::ajax` method, but then i edit it directly nothing changes. I tried log some debug info into file, but seem like this method not running at all (init method still running). All caches are turned off. Author of plugin not responding.

I want to apply `the_title` filter on titles of events, so it will be translated by WPMultilang plugin.

What should i do to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`WP_Fullcalendar::ajax` overrided by `WP_EventsManager` plugin in file `em-wpfc.php`, if wpfc and wpem used in combination.

Here is my final code in `functions.php`

```
/**
 * Translate WP_Fullcalendar titles for events
 * @param $items
 * @return array
 */
function wp_fc_translate($items)
{
    foreach ($items as &$item) {
        $item['title'] = apply_filters('the_title', $item['title']);
    }
    return $items;
}
add_action('wpfc_events', 'wp_fc_translate');
```

Comment: Yeah, lets downvote me for wasting so much time on unobvious question.